# Question about integration

Tags: calculus

I am currently revising some calculus notes, and I got a question I hope somebody could help me with. I seen the following done various places (not in my own notes, but in other proofs)

$\int \text{some-expression-in-terms-of-y  }\frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int \text{some-expression-in-terms-of-y  } dy$

I was told never to think of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a fraction, but rather as a symbol. So what exactly is happening there? Its like part of the integral is evaluated, changing the integral so its now with respect to $dy$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a fraction, and you are right not to think of it as a fraction. What you've seen is the substitution rule (the opposite of the chain rule you're used to), which states that 
$$\int{f(u(x))\cdot u'(x)} dx=\int{f(u)} du$$
You're not "cancelling" the dx you were integrating against before with the dx on the bottom - it's more like you're changing to a more convenient coordinate system.

The idea that you can "cross out" the dx's in $\frac{dy}{dx}dx$ to get dy is an abuse of notation that many nonrigorous, pedagogical texts adopt so their students can remember the rule better.

Comment: thank you very much, that cleared it up :)

Answer (score 3):

Let denote some-expression-in-terms-of-$y $ by $f(y)$ where $y$ is a function that depend to $x$. Now since $dy=y'(x) dx=\frac{dy}{dx}dx$ then  we have
$$\int f(y) y' dx=\int f(y) dy$$

Comment: and also, a big thanks to you :) I'll give the green tick to the other guy because he was a bit quicker with the answer.

Comment: You're welcome.